# Comparing the spatial frequency between groups of images

Tags: image-processing, matlab, frequency-domain

I have 2 groups of images, and I want to compare these groups based on the spatial frequencies of the images.
In the end, I'd like to be able to say "group A is/is not significantly different from group B based on spatial frequency" or something to that effect.

Can anyone think of a way to do this? [This question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/23695/comparison-between-2-images-in-frequency-domain) seems to touch on the topic, but as far as I can see it doesn't provide the solution I'm looking for (particularly not for groups of images).
MATLAB solutions would be the most valuable to me.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Did you find a matlab code that does it?

Comment: @user552231 I wish! Not yet. This would still be really valuable to me, if you have any ideas.